# Best type for ID column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am a beginner of SQL Server 2008. there a colunm in table like `StudentID`.
`StudentID` will be the pk of table, it only could be integer and it will be a huge number.

My question is what type for column StudentID in SQL Server 2008 is best?

`bigint`?
`numeric(18,0)`? or others?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 43):

You define a column of type `INT` (or `SMALLINT, TINYINT, BIGINT`) with the `IDENTITY` attribute:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ......
```

With this setup, SQL Server will automatically generate consecutive ID's for your table when rows are being inserted into your table.

With a type `INT`, starting at 1, you get **over 2 billion** possible rows - that should be more than sufficient for the vast majority of cases. With `BIGINT`, you get roughly **922 quadrillion** (922 with 15 zeros - 922'000 billions) - enough for you??

If you use an `INT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert a row every second, you need 66.5 **years** before you hit the 2 billion limit ... (so in my opinion, this is *more than enough* for the vast majority of cases!)

If you use a `BIGINT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert one thousand rows every second, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 922 quadrillion limit ....

`INT` uses 4 bytes of storage, while `BIGINT` uses 8 bytes. Especially if you deal with a large number of rows, and a number of non-clustered indexes, you want to keep this *as small as possible* - yet another reason why I typically pick `INT` as my "ID" type (unless I have a very strong indication that `INT` won't be enough...)

Read more about it (with all the options there are) in the [MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).

Comment: Hello sir, Thank you for changing a bit of the perspective of developing CMS level applications at wider level.

Comment: If you set the identity seed to the lowest negative number for the data type then you double the total number of values that can be stored in the column.

Answer (score 1):

**`Int`** is the Best type for Id column in a table in SQL Server

If the table eventually has too many records we can change to `BigInt`

We can also create the Id as the Identity and/or PK of the table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableName](
    [TableNameId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Example of Identity & Primary Key

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableName3](
    [TableName3Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableName3] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
    [TableName3Id] ASC
 )
)
```

Hope this helps your question helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes an int or any variation of int is a good choice ,but there is one downside to it which i can think of . When rows get deleted the ID field shows numbers missing like (1,3,4,5).
Guid could be second choice for ID field